# Change column names of nested data in bigquery using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write some data into BigQuery using Spark Scala, My spark df looks like,

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cost: double (nullable = false)
 |-- nodes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- settled: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- constant: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to change the struct of the data frame.

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", StringType, true),
  StructField("cost", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("nodes", StructType(Array(StructField("settled", StringType), StructField("constant", StringType)))),
  StructField("status", StringType, true)))

val actualDf = spark.createDataFrame(results, schema)
```

But it didn't work. When this writes into the BigQuery, Column names look like as follows,

**id, cost, nodes.list.element.settled, nodes.list.element.constant, status**

Is there a possible way to change these column names as,

**id, cost, settled, constant, status**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **`explode`** nodes array to get flatten structure of columns, then write dataframe to bigquery.

Example:

```
val jsn_ds=Seq("""{"id":1, "cost": "2.0","nodes":[{"settled":"u","constant":"p"}],"status":"s"}""").toDS

spark.read.json(jsn_ds).printSchema
// root
// |-- cost: string (nullable = true)
// |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |-- nodes: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- constant: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- settled: string (nullable = true)
// |-- status: string (nullable = true)

spark.read.json(jsn_ds).
      withColumn("expld",explode('nodes)).
      select("*","expld.*").
      drop("expld","nodes").
      show()

//+----+---+------+--------+-------+
//|cost| id|status|constant|settled|
//+----+---+------+--------+-------+
//| 2.0|  1|     s|       p|      u|
//+----+---+------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the following error. `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) nodes#106 missing from id#178,cost#179,nodes#180,status#181 in operator !Generate explode(nodes#106), true, false, [expld#188];;
Project [id#178, cost#179, nodes#180, status#181, expld#188]
+- !Generate explode(nodes#106), true, false, [expld#188]
   +- LogicalRDD [id#178, cost#179, nodes#180, status#181]`
Code,
`spark.read.json(results.toJSON).withColumn("expld", explode(results.col("nodes"))).select("*", "expld.*").drop("expld", "nodes").show()`

Comment: Try this `spark.read.json(results.toJSON).withColumn("expld", explode(col("nodes"))).select("*", "expld.*").drop("expld", "nodes").show() `